# JPA mapping for Parent-Child with same class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, parent-child

I have following table:

```
FOLDER[
    id int,
    name varchar2(10),
    parent_folder_id int
]
```

I would like to have Folder class to have parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe the correct mapping would be:

```
@Entity
public class Folder {

    @Id
    @Column(name="PK_FOLDER")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_PARENT_FOLDER")
    public Folder parentFolder;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentFolder")
    public List<Folder> subFolders = new ArrayList<Folder>();

}
```

The `@OneToOne` would work only if each parent had at most one child, the above code works for the more general case, when a parent can have many children. Also, I'm omitting get/set methods for simplicity's sake.

Comment: This looks pretty good, except that it should be a `Set<>`, not a `List<>`.

Comment: Both Collections are fine, a List might be of use for maintaining insertion order, a Set for enforcing uniqueness - it really depends on the particular case, as both are valid and the specification doesn't enforce the use of one over the other. As a matter of fact, many code generators for JPA mapping default to using ArrayLists for the @OneToMany relationship.

Comment: hi, When i fire list all query. It goes in infinite loop. Can you guide me ?

Comment: @JigarShah you should add annotation JsonIgnore before  JoinColumn(name="FK_PARENT_FOLDER")

Comment: I was experiencing problems while trying to delete such entities. Adding `orphanRemoval` flag solved it for me. So, it goes like this: `@OneToMany(mappedBy="parentFolder", orphanRemoval=true)`

Comment: The best, It's make the product Category, Variant real dynamic. And So damn Easy :D