# Caused by: javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2 For Save data

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I can not save Data. When I saved post request got error?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ALKP")
public class ALKP {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   private String title;
   @Column(name = "KEYWORD")
   private String keyword;
   private String code;
   private Long slNo;
   private String fullName;
   private boolean isActive;

   @CreationTimestamp
   @Column(name = "created_at",updatable = false)
   private LocalDate createDate;

   @UpdateTimestamp
   @Column(name = "updated_at")
   private LocalDateTime updateDateTime;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="parentId")
   public ALKP parentId;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentId")
   public Set<ALKP> subALKP = new HashSet<>();
```

Data ::

```
PostMan Body Request Data
{
    "title": "FeMale",
    "keyword": "GENDER_FEMALE",
    "slNo": 2,
    "active": true,
    "code": "MC-00209",
    "fullName": "FEMALE",
    "parentId":700
}
```

"message": "detached entity passed to persist error in Spring Boot when consuming a rest service",
When I saved data it can not be catch Parent ALKP . I think It can be

parentId:{
"id":700
}

Comment: Show your code that you are hitting to db, What are you trying to receive. Show us logic.

Comment: @PawełGłowacz 
It can not catch Parent ID as Request Body Attribute

Answer (score 0):

seems your ALKP enity have same parentId. or your defined the association mab be wrong.

```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="parentId")
   public ALKP parentId;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentId")
   public Set<ALKP> subALKP = new HashSet<>();
```

Above both are pointng same ALKP and its Id then how can you get one and many object in same enity?

Comment: I followed this Ques: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584764/jpa-mapping-for-parent-child-with-same-class
@Muthu