# Unlimited Hierarchical child parent relationship in the same table using JPA (TreeView)

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I am trying to create a "Category and Subcategories" Entity, i tried to do some research but i couldn't find a good solution, i need a light on how can i model this Entity and have the bellow result! Be able to retrieve the data in this tree view format.

```
   {
"id": 1,
"name": "Account 1",
"children": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Account 1.1",
        "parent": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Account 1"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Account 1.2",
        "parent": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Account 1"
        },
        children: [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Account 1.2.1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "Account 1.2.1.1",
                        "parent": {
                            "id": 4,
                            "name": "Account 1.2.1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "Account 1.2.1.2",
                        "parent": {
                            "id": 4,
                            "name": "Account 1.2.1"
                        },
                        children: [
                        
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: This looks like a recursion. A "Category" will have a couple of child categories and each of them has a couple of categories again. This might be one to many relationship. Again not sure. Shared my thoughts.

Comment: Why would a Child's parent also be in its list of children?  A4 has both A1 as its parent and in its list of children - A1 should have A4 marked as its parent, so this JSON seems incorrect. Otherwise, this is a simple 1:M with a M:1 back pointer in JPA. For JSON, this circular loop needs a stop; you should pick one 'side' to only include the IDs, possibly by using JsonIdentityReference where appropriate or you'll get a stackoverflowexception. JsonIdentityReference should ensure only the ID value is used to indicate the reference, stopping recursive loops.

Comment: Sorry, i fixed the Json, i hope now what i need is clear.

Comment: here similar question with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584764/jpa-mapping-for-parent-child-with-same-class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA mapping for Parent-Child with same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584764/jpa-mapping-for-parent-child-with-same-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can construct this recursive tree like structure in a single database table ( Entity, in spring data jpa ) and fetch the whole tree upto leaf nodes with two database call, if we design our model carefully.

Before start table design / Entity modeling lets boil down some facts

1. Every Category should have a parent category if it is a subcategory, otherwise the category is the root category
2. Every Category which is subcategory must have a root category.

**Category.java**

```java
@Entity
public class Category {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long categoryId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Category parentCategory;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "root_category_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Category rootCategory;
    
    @Transient
    public List<Category> childrens = new ArrayList<Category>();
}
```

**CategoryRepository.java**

```java
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {
    
    @Query("SELECT category FROM Category category "
            + " WHERE category.parentCategory.categoryId IS NULL")
    public List<Category> findAllRoots();

    @Query("SELECT category FROM Category category"
            + " WHERE category.rootCategory.categoryId IN :rootIds ")
    public List<Category> findAllSubCategoriesInRoot(@Param("rootIds") List<Long> rootIds);
}
```

**CategoryController.java**

```java
@RestController
public class CategoryController {
    
    @Autowired
    public CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @GetMapping("/categories")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        List<Category> rootCategories = categoryRepository.findAllRoots(); // first db call

        // Now Find all the subcategories
        List<Long> rootCategoryIds = rootCategories.stream().map(Category::getCategoryId).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Category> subCategories = categoryRepository.findAllSubCategoriesInRoot(rootCategoryIds); // second db call

        subCategories.forEach(subCategory -> {
            subCategory.getParentCategory().getChildrens().add(subCategory); // no further db call, because everyone inside the root is in the persistence context.
        });

        return rootCategories;
    }
}
```

**Sample dataset**

```sql
-- root
INSERT INTO category (category_id, name, parent_category_id, root_category_id) VALUES (1, 'A', null, null);

-- first level
INSERT INTO category (category_id, name, parent_category_id, root_category_id) VALUES (2, 'B', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO category (category_id, name, parent_category_id, root_category_id) VALUES (3, 'C', 1, 1);

-- second level
INSERT INTO category (category_id, name, parent_category_id, root_category_id) VALUES (4, 'D', 2, 1);
INSERT INTO category (category_id, name, parent_category_id, root_category_id) VALUES (5, 'E', 3, 1);
INSERT INTO category (category_id, name, parent_category_id, root_category_id) VALUES (6, 'F', 3, 1);

-- another root
INSERT INTO category (category_id, name, parent_category_id, root_category_id) VALUES (7, 'P', null, null);

-- first level of another root
INSERT INTO category (category_id, name, parent_category_id, root_category_id) VALUES (8, 'Q', 7, 7);
INSERT INTO category (category_id, name, parent_category_id, root_category_id) VALUES (9, 'R', 7, 7);
```

**Generated response**

```json
[
    {
        "categoryId": 1,
        "name": "A",
        "childrens": [
            {
                "categoryId": 2,
                "name": "B",
                "childrens": [
                    {
                        "categoryId": 4,
                        "name": "D",
                        "childrens": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "categoryId": 3,
                "name": "C",
                "childrens": [
                    {
                        "categoryId": 5,
                        "name": "E",
                        "childrens": []
                    },
                    {
                        "categoryId": 6,
                        "name": "F",
                        "childrens": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "categoryId": 7,
        "name": "P",
        "childrens": [
            {
                "categoryId": 8,
                "name": "Q",
                "childrens": []
            },
            {
                "categoryId": 9,
                "name": "R",
                "childrens": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I intentionally skipped the `parent` as per your sample response because adding the parent in the body will unnecessarily increase the response size.

If you really need that `parent` key in all the sub categories, then you have to introduce another POJO (not entity) containing the `id` & `name` of the parent category and copy the parent category `id` & `name` into that POJO and set it to the corresponding sub category.