# How to query using a single column of a composite primary key using spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a table with a composite primary key (column1, column2). I'm writing a spring-boot application with spring-data-jpa.

I want to find all records in the said table using column1. Then,
I want to find all records in the said table using column2

How is this possible using spring-data-jpa.

I'm adding the link to my demo project. It has a CompanyRelationship table with a composite primary key. Kindly help.
https://github.com/abhijitnath90/h2-demo/tree/main

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest revisiting how you work with recursive relationships in JPA. Perhaps look at [Unlimited Hierarchical child parent relationship in the same table using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72464777/unlimited-hierarchical-child-parent-relationship-in-the-same-table-using-jpa-tr)

Comment: I solved the problem i.e. I'm able to findByPrimaryKeyClassIndividualColumn(String column). However, this table structure cannot be changed as this is a dummy table for an  actual table in production. The actual table in production has similar structure and I just replicated the table structures and relationships. Thanks for understanding!